# Много угля или углей

Tags: согласование, падежи, единственное-множественное-число

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, как  правильно сказать: "В Донбассе много угля или углей?"

Answer (score 7):

В Донбассе много угля - твёрдого горючего вещества.
А углей много в печи - кусков древесного угля.

Answer (score 1):

Много угля - т.е. природного горючего материала.

Answer (score 1):

Углей там будет много, если в Донбассе, например, сожгут лес.))) А вот в земных недрах много угля — полезного ископаемого.
Так что, Вы определитесь, о чем идет речь.